# Compare aggregated value for groups to the aggregated value for the entire table

Tags: sql

Let's say I have one table that has E_name, DepartmentName, Salary

```
E_name  DepartmentName  Salary
AAA     D1              1000
BBB     D1              1400
CCC     D2              1320
DDD     D2              1100
EEE     D3              900
FFF     D3              1200
```

how to show DepartmentName where their employees' average salary is bigger than the average of all employees

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, postgres, oracle?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should really attempt to solve these exercises yourself.  For instance, you might start with calculating the average salary over all employees.

Comment: i'm using SQL server

Comment: Are you familiar with `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @GordonLinoffI know how to calculate the average salary for all employees but in the where condition

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes i know how to group the query

Comment: average salary or salary > avg of all employees in that dept

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja not Excatly avg salary of department > avg salary of all employees

Comment: Next time try to include what things you are already tried so we can focus on what is missing. In this case looks like you dont know how to work with a simple group by, but if instead you show us you already calculate the all employees avg we focus on the part to join boths averages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` clause

```
select DepartmentName  
  from employees
 group by DepartmentName
 having avg(Salary) > ( select avg(salary) from employees );
```

Comment: You took it as a whole > for all depts. was that the query ohh :( i did for each dept.

Comment: That's was helpful Thank You,
 for another situation can I use a subquery with WHERE clause

Comment: @OmarMohamed you're welcome. Of course you can, but it's important to detect the right column to be bound for subqueries. By the way `having` is very similar to `where`. i.e. `where` for `aggregations`

Comment: @Omar Mohamed Could you please upvote my answer too it was just i compared within the dept but the only diff is why here subquery is used just get avg of all sal of emp in the whole table not group this is the thing i wanted from you to be cleared

Answer (score 0):

```
 select dept_name,sal 
 group by dept_name 
 having sal > avg(sal);`
```

Did you mean this ? as this says all the dept groups having any of the salary > avg of all the salaries of that dept give that result.

Comment: is that code will compare the avg salary of the employees within a dept to the avg salary of all employees?

Comment: see in this case it is doing like suppose i have sal 1000,2000 so the avg is 3000/2=1500 my query will work like 1000>=1000(say equal to as well suppose),display else like in this case 1000>=2000, no so itll not display. This is for a particular dept

Answer (score 0):

I'd join between an aggregate query that's grouped by department and an aggregate query that isn't grouped:

```
SELECT DepartmentName, AvgDepartmentSalary
FROM   (SELECT   DepartmentName, AVG(Salary) AS AvgDepartmentSalary
        FROM     employees
        GROUP BY DepartmentName) g
JOIN   (SELECT AVG(Salary) AS AverageSalary
        FROM   employee) u ON AvgDepartmentSalary > AverageSalary
```

Comment: Did not get why you did like this ?